# How to push Activity content up when Keyboard activated

Tags: android

In an `Activity` of my `Application`, the user has to submit many Strings trough an `EditText` and a `Button`. As the range of the submits can go from a **minimum** of **9** to a **maximum** of **24**, I want this process to be as easy and fast as possible.

I was thinking about making the **Keyboard always visible** while the whole **Activity content** gets **pushed up**.

---

I have tried to use the following rule in the `Manifest` to make it push the Activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but it looks like it only pushes up the content with a marginBottom.

Any ideas bout how to achieve this?

EDIT:

The following is the XML code of the Layout of my Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.FET.leonardo.scurcola.NameSelection"
android:background="#e0ab18">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/whoMaster"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/whoMaster"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/master"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/names"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:onClick="addPlayer"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/names"
    android:textColor="#e0ab18" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:onClick="removePlayer"
    android:textColor="#e0ab18"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/names" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/finish"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/finish"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/names"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:onClick="toNextActivity"
    android:textColor="#e0ab18"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/zero"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/playersLeft"
    android:layout_below="@+id/names"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting that option `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, you can try using a `ScrollView`

Having so many fields can have some downside to your application speed - since every single element has to be drawn and that can be expensive. This will in turn affect your UI thread and could eventually cause app crashing.

Using a `ScrollView`, you can be able to scroll up and down through your `EditText` elements.

To speed up your application loading, for example if you have a lot more EditTexts, you can load half the elements/widgets when activity is loaded and once the user has started typing into the first field, load the rest.

This is an approach I have used several times and should work just fine!

Good luck and please let me know if this helps!

**UPDATE**

To have a scrollable view, make your root layout a `ScrollView` - remember it can only have 1 child.

```
<ScrollView 
   ....
   ....
   ..... >

   <RelativeLayout
      ....
      ....
      ..... >

      <EditText />
      ...
   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

So, basically you have a ScrollView as the root! That will enable you to scroll up the view and have the keyboard below or at the bottom!

Comment: Hey, I've added my XML layout code, may I ask you however how to do that ScrollView?

Comment: I've updated my code, but it seems like only the buttons got pushed up, and they're the only ones to have a marginBottom, weird, will leave you my updated XML